# Is .git folder crossplatform?

Tags: windows, linux, git

If the .git folder that was created using linux is copied to windows, will it work?

Comment: @Shep because I am using git-svn in a huuuge repository, copying my .git will save me a few hours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it will be okay - I work like this myself - on two computers with Linux and Windows `.git` directory is synced by dropbox, and there are absolutely no problems at all :)

btw - `.hg` works equally well.

Comment: seems like a weird workflow... So is the entire working tree also synced by dropbox?

Comment: Well, it's my master's thesis, so it's not large tree :] but I did worked like this on small java projects etc, where I didn't pushed it anywhere, just worked on local repo. Fun and easy, while project is small :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes I am using it with [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) extension on Linux and msysGit + TortoiseGit on Windows it uses the `.git` folder well.

But be very careful with the inverse. By copying git folders from Windows to Linux there will be :

1. many Windows carriage returns in files
2. files permission changes

MsysGit manages it well on Windows but on Linux before commit/push you will have to : use [dos2unix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) for 1. and `chmod 644` on files for 2. `git status` and `git diff` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is, I've worked with the same repo from both Windows and Linux boxes and it works fine. When you work in Git Windows, everytime you push to a remote Linux repo, git will convert the line ending from Windows to Linux style.

Comment: sure, but it doesn't sound like that's what the OP is asking. If I'm not mistaken, the `.git` directory is being copied directly, not cloned / pushed / pulled.

Comment: I don't think git changes line endings, it is probably your text editor/IDE that is changing the line endings. In the git config, you can also set to ignore line endings changes. http://help.github.com/line-endings/

Comment: Git will change line ending at the point of `add`ing the file, but only if the config settings request it. A similar process happens when the file is checked out. For a mixed environment it is common that the in-repo settings are Linux LF style, with the Windows boxes doing the changes they expect. Copying the `.git` directory doesn't change that common setting for the repo content.